# Getting siblings value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I create a textarea and a button on a loop based on a certain condition:

```
while($row_c= mysqli_fetch_array($result_comments))
{
//some code goes here

<textarea type="text" id="pm_text" name="text"></textarea><br>
<button name="send_comment" id="post_comment" class="button" onClick="post_pm_comment()">Post</button>
}
```

Now in my function "post_pm_comment" I would like to access the text written in the textarea when the post button is clicked.

I tried this, but it only gives me the text of the first textarea and button created:

```
function post_pm_comment(thidid, pm_id, path, pm,getter)
{
    var pm_text = document.getElementById("pm_text").value;
}
```

What should I do?
Thank you

Comment: Well, you should show us your HTML, for a start... (the [tag:php] is irrelevant to JavaScript, it's what the browser sees that's important, 'view source').

Comment: I did show you how the html is created. Its just a textarea and a button that triggers a function onclick.

Comment: Crowder's answer is definitely way to do it. But looks like you want some other parameters too as per your post_pm_comment function. What those arguments doing there and where are you getting those? Looks like this code snippet is not complete. May be you should first post real code to get better answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is outputting an invalid DOM structure, because `id` values **must** be unique on the page. You cannot have the same `id` on more than one element. Remove the `id` values entirely, you don't need them.

Having done that, the minimal-changes answer is to pass `this` into your handler:

```
onClick="post_pm_comment(this)"
```

...and then in your handler, do the navigation:

```
function post_pm_comment(postButton)
{
    var pm_text;
    var textarea = postButton.previousSibling;
    while (textarea && textarea.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== "TEXTAREA") {
        textarea = textarea.previousSibling;
    }
    if (textarea) {
        pm_text = textarea.value; // Or you may want .innerHTML instead
        // Do something with it
    }
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/iPUWIyi/1/edit) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/iPUWIyi/1/edit)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply but when I alert(pm_text) nothing happens.
I dont get the text that I've typed inside the textarea

Comment: Crowder's answer is definitely way to do it. But looks like you want some other parameters too as per your post_pm_comment function. What those arguments doing there and where are you getting those? Looks like this code snippet is not complete. May be you should first post real code to get better answer here.

Comment: @beckinho: There was a typo in an earlier version of this answer which might account for that. (I had `var textarea = postButton.prevSibling;` where I should have had `var textarea = postButton.previousSibling;`) I've fixed the typo since, and just now added a live example.

Comment: I made the mistake of putting the alert inside the if statement, Im so sorry for my mistake. Mr Crowder's code is right. Thank you very much

Comment: @beckinho: *"I made the mistake of putting the alert inside the if statement"* That's where it would belong, I think the problem was probably my early typo. :-)